# color texts at expect shell

Tags: colors, expect, puts

As the title, is there any way to use color texts at expect shell?
Like the shell script echo command below.

```
echo -e "\033[32m Hello World"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been suffering the answer to this question for quite some time, and now I think I've finally got an answer.

How it works is to use `033` to send the < ESC> character and then `[` to send ANSI escape codes separated by semicolons, however as `[` is a special character it also needs to be escaped with a backslash. You can then proceed to send ANSI sequences and delimit with an `m`.

Example ANSI break sequences

- 0 Reset / Normal all attributes off
- 1 Bold or increased intensity
- 4 Underline: Single
- 30 Set text color Black
- 31 Set text color Red
- 32 Set text color Green

Full list can be found here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Example:

```
puts "\033\[01;31m" # This will turn text red
puts "~~~This text is red and bold\n" 
puts "\033\[0;32m" # This will turn text green
puts "This text is green and bold switched off\n"
```

However it doesn't seem to work with the `-nonewline` option, which is a tad annoying. However the send_user command seems to handle things a lot better and under control a lot better:

```
send_user "\033\[01;31mRed bold \033\[0;32mGreen again"
```

You can even combine this with variables to make the output more readable:

```
set green "\033\[0;32;40m"
set red "\033\[1;31m"
send_user "${red}Red bold ${green}Green again"
```

Comment: Life saver man :), this is very nice.  For that that want to reset, I created a normal variable and put, set normal "\033\[0;0m"